# "Tick" does not show on "software source"

Tags: 11.04, updates, repository, software-sources

I'm having update issues with 11.04. Read one possible solution about selecting "software sources" in the repository. The thing is i can not select it, (tick it) just shows a line "-". Why is this? Any idea?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Refering the update issues: Did you try `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal - does it give you an error message?

Refering the "tick": When I (in 11.10) tick this I get asked for the root-password. Then it's no problem. I regrettably have no idea ...